# Grafana alerts test notification sent but no email has been received

Tags: smtp, grafana

I wanted to test Grafana alerts. I want to receive email when there is an alert. So first I have setup the SMTP in grafana.ini file:

```
#################################### SMTP / Emailing##########################
[smtp]
enabled = true
host = localhost:25 
user = 
# If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with trippel quotes. Ex """#password;"""
password = 
;cert_file =
;key_file =
skip_verify = true
from_address = admin@grafana.localhost
from_name = Grafana

[emails]
;welcome_email_on_sign_up = false
```

In the test in the Grafana, I have set name, type:Email, send on all alerts, include image.
My email is on hotmail.

When i press send test, I receive Test notification sent, but there is no email received...

Here is the log:

```
t=2018-07-06T11:09:54+0000 lvl=eror msg="can't read datasource provisioning files from directory" logger=provisioning.datasources path=/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources
t=2018-07-06T11:09:54+0000 lvl=info msg="Initializing RenderingService" logger=server
t=2018-07-06T11:09:54+0000 lvl=info msg="Initializing TracingService" logger=server
t=2018-07-06T11:09:54+0000 lvl=info msg="Initializing Stream Manager"
t=2018-07-06T11:09:54+0000 lvl=info msg="HTTP Server Listen" logger=http.server address=0.0.0.0:3000 protocol=http subUrl= socket=
t=2018-07-06T11:09:54+0000 lvl=eror msg="can't read dashboard provisioning files from directory" logger=provisioning.dashboard path=/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
t=2018-07-06T11:09:57+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending alert notification to" logger=alerting.notifier.email addresses=[myEmail@gmail.com]
t=2018-07-06T11:09:57+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending alert notification to" logger=alerting.notifier.email addresses=[myEmail@gmail.com]
t=2018-07-06T11:10:26+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending alert notification to" logger=alerting.notifier.email addresses=[myEmail@hotmail.com]
t=2018-07-06T11:10:27+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending alert notification to" logger=alerting.notifier.email addresses=[myEmail@hotmail.com]
t=2018-07-06T11:12:31+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending alert notification to" logger=alerting.notifier.email addresses=[myEmail@hotmail.com]
```

I have tested with gmail too, and it is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an SMTP server listening on localhost port 25?  If not, you'll either need to run one or use a valid SMTP config for Grafana.  If you are, you need to check the mail server logs to see what it's doing with the emails.

Comment: What you mean by: or use a valid SMTP config for Grafana? About the log, I have posted it.

Comment: Grafana isn't a mail server, it needs to be able the send email to a mail server via SMTP.  Your Grafana configuration has `host = localhost:25` in the `[smtp]` section meaning that Grafana is going to try to send email to a mailserver listening on port 25 on the local machine.

Comment: The simplest way to enable Grafana to send email will be to configure it to use an external SMTP server, for less than 10000 emails per month you can use https://www.mailgun.com for free

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Mailgun is free but is sending email only to not authorized emails. If the email is authorized I need to upgrade my Account... DO you know any other solution? I have heard about Postfix, is it good?

Comment: @xmlParser postfix is a popular mailserver, but running a mail server is a non-trivial exercise and definitely outside the scope of your question.  I'm not aware of any limitation in mailgun that restricts free accounts to authorized recipients. https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faqs.html#what-are-the-differences-between-free-and-paid-accounts